# Preserver Component State in Angular

Tags: angular

I am building a Web App with the ability to draw on a map. I have a settings menu which is just another component which I call over an `router.navigateByUrl();` call. Same on the way back.

The problem now is that on the way, everything in the component is loaded again. The Map with all its drawings is gone. Authentification is gone (Well I probably should move that into services anyway), and more. I just can't shift everything into services.

Is it possible to preserve the state of the component so that it stays loaded?

Thanks Alot!

Comment: NgRx or localStorage might help you.

Comment: Can you post an example of your component structure

Comment: Is there a reason for choosing navigatebyUrl() rather than navigate() ?

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way to solve this would be to use a service, call it Map Service for example. Then in this service you have a property or an observable that holds all the data about the drawings. When the user navigates back to the component, you get all the data from the Map Service and redraw.

If you do not want to use a service, there is a couple of other ways of doing this. You don't necessarily need to use the router, you could just use the hidden property on the element. When the user opens the menu, you hide the map. When he leaves the menu you show it again. Something like:

```
<app-my-map-component [hidden]="menuIsOpen">
<app-my-menu-component *ngIf="menuIsOpen">
```

Although I would say that if you plan on your app to grow big, you should probably use the Router and services from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

When route is changed the associated component is indeed destroyed. So although you could save the state of the component but you will still be initialising  the component again when you hit that route.

Solutions:

1. May be you should use css to hide and show the component instead of route change.
2. Create an instance of the component using `ComponentFactoryResolver`. And when you are ready to display this component then create it using 'ViewContainerRef.createComponent' and set all the properties on it(e.g. isAuthenticated, map related props etc). To do this of course you will have to save the state of this component in a service.
3. For this also you will have to save the state. You could use queryParams to pass on the values to component.